# Can I make elements that are set to justify-content: space-between align to the right when they wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two elements in a container that are set to "display flex" and "justify-content space-between." This makes them display on the opposite side of each other in the container. If the container shrinks I would like the element on the left to stack on top of the element on the right and align to the right. The behavior I am experiencing now is that they wrap, but the item on the left is above the right element and is aligned to the left, while the element on the right is aligned to the right. How do I make them both align right?

Please keep in mind I can't use a media query because I have multiple cells that will have varying data. So the items will need to wrap at multiple media sizes that I won't be aware of beforehand. Please see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/London804/pen/deWYjb) for more details.

```css
.u-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.u-centerY {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.u-fillRemaining {
  flex: 1;
}

.u-spaceBetweenX {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.u-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Rtable-cell {
  padding: 0 0.625rem;
  max-width: 12rem;
  min-width: 6.25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-sum {
  // visibility: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: Grey;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.t-alignRight {
  text-align: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .u-spaceBetweenX {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="u-relative Rtable-cell">
  <div class="u-centerY u-fillRemaining u-spaceBetweenX u-wrap">
    <span class="table-sum">sum</span>
    <div class="u-fillRemaining t-alignRight">
      <p>$4,000,000.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`justify-content: flex-end` makes the elements inside the flex container align to the right.

setting `flex: 1 0 6rem` means that the value area can grow, **can't shrink**, and its basic size is half the parent size.

once the size of the container shrinks beyond the point the two items can fit in the same row, the second item wraps to the 2nd row, which makes the first element stick to the right (because of the `justify-content: flex-end`.

if you want the effect to when there's not enough space for the text, you can make the `value` container shrink as well by setting the second parameter to `1`. it won't shrink beyond its content:

```
flex: 1 1 6rem; /* now the minimum size can be less than 6rem if the text is shorter */
```

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $('.width-change').toggleClass('short');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.kb-container {
  padding: 0 0.625rem;
  max-width: 12rem;
  min-width: 6.25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: white;
}

.kb-value {
  flex: 1 0 6rem;
  text-align: right;
}


/* not necessary. just for this demo */

.width-change {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 7rem;
  transition: all 250ms;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.width-change.short {
  width: 9rem;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sub {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.kb-example {
  width: 45vw;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
}

.kb-example.kb-colorized .kb-text {
background-color: #ccffcc;
}

.kb-example.kb-colorized .kb-value {
background-color: #ccffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kb-example">
  <h3>align items to the right using flex</h3>
  <div class="sub">(container will resize to demo the behavior)</div>
  <div class="width-change">
    <!-- YOU ONLY NEED THIS -->
    <div class="kb-container">
      <span class="kb-text">sum</span>
      <div class="kb-value">
        $4,000,000.00
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- with colorized elements -->
<div class="kb-example kb-colorized">
  <div class="sub">and now with x-ray:</div>
  <div class="width-change">
    <!-- YOU ONLY NEED THIS -->
    <div class="kb-container">
      <span class="kb-text">sum</span>
      <div class="kb-value">
        $4,000,000.00
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END -->
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/aGWNoB?editors=0100) as well (this contains only the code you need for this behavior without the extra code for the demo)

Even though this is a `flex-end` container, it behaves like a `space-between` flex container because the second item grows and it's text is aligned to the right

Comment: Thank you, that worked! My solution was really close I just had to remove justify-content: space between. I have one question though, what does the "0 and 6 rem" do inside the flex property? I just used flex: 1 and it worked the same.

Comment: @London804 you don't have to use it. it's the same as setting `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. `flex-basis` gives a base size. if you'll set `flex-shrink` to `0` and add a `flex-basis`, that will be the minimum size (unless you set `width` as well).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code and change the 400px to whatever you want

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .u-spaceBetweenX {
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
}
```

and if you want the items to align left change `justify-content: flex-start`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a media query? I have table with a lot of data and sometimes the container will be small and the data will be small so it won't matter. I want it to adjust based on how much space is in the container and that can happen at any screen size.

Comment: I think you need to write a script for that to check the table or the container width and change the style based on that.

Comment: That wouldn't work either because it don't want it to change based on the width of the container. I want it to change based on the data in the container.

Comment: @London804 you can do this with CSS only and no media queries. check my answer